# Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error 'package:bloc/src/transition.dart': Failed assertion: line 27 pos 16: 'nextState != null': is not true

Tags: flutter, bloc

I am getting  this error while updating a value in state . please suggest me how to resolve it. what is best way to update current state while working with BLOC in flutter. My BLOC class code added. This Error Occurs onItemClick Event.

```
 onItemClicked: (e) async* {
      try {
        yield walmartState;

        List<CommonDataObj> dataList =
            walmartItemChanged(e.index, e.walmartList);
        yield state.copyWith(walmartList: some(right(dataList)));
        LinkedHashMap<String, RequestData> reqMap = state.requestDataMap;
        dataList.forEach((element) {
          if (element.isSelected) {
            RequestData data = RequestData(element.intStoreId, element.intId);
            if (reqMap.containsKey(e.key)) {
              reqMap.update(e.key, (value) => data);
            } else {
              reqMap.putIfAbsent(e.key, () => data);
            }
          } else {
            if (reqMap.containsKey(e.key)) {
              var value = reqMap[e.key];
              if (value.int_product_id == element.intId &&
                  value.int_store_id == element.intStoreId) {
                reqMap.remove(e.key);
              }
            }
          }
        });

        yield state.copyWith(requestDataMap: reqMap);
        yield state.copyWith(requestDataMap: reqMap);
        print('State request Data Map : $reqMap');
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }

      try {
        bool selected = false;
        e.currentDataMap.forEach((key, value) {
          for (var item in value) {
            if (item.isSelected) {
              selected = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        });

        int curQuantity = state.currentQuantity;
        if (curQuantity == 0) {
          curQuantity = curQuantity + 1;
        } else if (curQuantity > 0 && !selected) {
          curQuantity = 0;
        }
        var newState = state.copyWith(currentQuantity: curQuantity);
        yield newState;
      } catch (e) {
        print(e);
      }
    }
```

Comment: try to restart the app instead of hot reload

Comment: I tried restarting the app , even i uninstalled the app, but not resolved

Comment: add code please!

Comment: @MajidAli sample code added

Comment: does this work: https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/253